# Why are Dataproc cluster properties not in the info panel?

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc

In the Google Cloud Console I have opened the "info" panel for a cluster but I only see labels and permissions. What I really want to see is the cluster properties, such as the Spark and YARN properties.

How can I see cluster properties?

Answer (score 1):

The info panel is generally consistent in the Cloud Console inside and outside of Dataproc. The info panel usually shows labels and IAM permissions.

To see [cluster properties](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/cluster-properties#console):

1. Open a cluster's detail in the Cloud Console (click the cluster)
2. Click 'Configuration'
3. Expand 'Properties'

You can also use the gcloud command to list properties.

`gcloud dataproc clusters describe`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what James has posted above, you can also click on REST equivalent link on bottom left to see all the information in one go.